# How To Modify Tax Calculations in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax, core

For Testing - Learning purposes I would like to modify Tax Calculations in my magento installation. (not for production so no problem to modify core files).

Based on the fact that Taxes are displayed on catalog, cart, orders, etc I believe it will provide me enhanced details about some magento functionalities i cannot fully understand right now. Consequently my main idea is to learn how it works in terms of:

1. Original Price multiply by a Tax rate.
2. Price Calculations including Tax rate based on a shipping location.
3. Price Including Taxes displayed in different design areas.

Tax Model is so complex i cannot find the appropiated class defining those details. Any help like php file containing that logic, explanation or tutorial on the web will be greatly appreciated.

brgds!

UPDATE!-------------------------------------------------------------------------

TAX Calculations are mainly handled by shipping, billing or default address. Calculations resides in Tax/Model/Calculation.php
if you modify calcTaxAmount function, the amount taxed to products, sales, quote, cart, etc. change in design.

Based on the fact shipping, billing address is displayed when user log into the system my idea is to test including a cookie with country destination information, based on Location detecting tecniques with IP addresses. it seems public function getRate($request) has the answer.
i will continue working.. any help for cookie management appreciated!.

Comment: you should write your update as an answer and accept it. even if it may not be a full answer, it's a push in the right direction.